# iba a + infinitivo con valor de condicional

Tags: verbos, condicional

En las oraciones:

> No pensé que iba a volver a verte.
>
> Todos sabíamos que iba a fallar.

iba a + infinitivo puede ser reemplazado por el condicional del infinitivo, como en:

> No pensé que volvería a verte.
>
> Todos sabíamos que fallaría.

¿Existe alguna referencia formal que se refiera a esta construcción de algún organismo lingüístico?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Son dos maneras distintas de expresar el "futuro en el pasado". Se corresponden con las dos formas de expresar el futuro simple.

Si decimos

> Todos **sabíamos** que **iba a fallar**

es porque en el pasado decíamos

> Todos **sabemos** que **va a fallar**.

La perífrasis "va a + infinitivo" indica futuro, pero está conjugada en el presente. Para que indique "futuro en el pasado", simplemente se conjuga el verbo *ir* en el pretérito imperfecto.

Y si decimos

> Todos **sabíamos** que **fallaría**

es porque en el pasado decíamos

> Todos **sabemos** que **fallará**.

Para colocar "fallará" en el pasado usamos el condicional, porque es su función.

Resumiendo:

- *va a fallar* → *iba a fallar*
- *fallará* → *fallaría*

---

Descripción del condicional en el *Manual de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (extracto):

**23.8.1a**  El condicional simple designa una situación posterior a otra pretérita, por lo que ha sido caracterizado como un “futuro del pasado” (pospretérito en el sistema de Andrés Bello). Es, pues, un tiempo relativo y presenta puntos de contacto tanto con el futuro como con el pretérito imperfecto.